# SKCropNode doesn't crop when mask is gradient

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add a mask to a SKSpriteNode, where the mask is a gradient( as attached)[image]

```
 let image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
 let mask = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mask")

 let fadeMask = SKCropNode() 
 fadeMask.maskNode = mask
        
       
 fadeMask.addChild(image)
        
 addChild(fadeMask)
```

but the image is not masked at all. Is it possbile that the image of the mask is not suitable to be a mask? can't do a gradient as a mask?

Answer (score 0):

the crop node draws pixels based on whether the mask is alpha or opaque. this logic is hard-edged, i.e. *not* a continuously blended gradient.

according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skcropnode/1520449-masknode): "If the pixel in the mask has an alpha value of less than 0.05, the image pixel is masked out."

however you can achieve your desired effect in other ways. for instance, here is an example that uses a shader. admittedly more cumbersome, but it works.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let shader_gradient_sourcecode = """
void main() {
    float alpha = 1 - v_tex_coord.x; //set alpha to x value for a horizontal gradient
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, alpha);
}
"""
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
        let mask = SKShapeNode(rectOf: image.size) //make mask same size as primary image

        //init shader and assign it to the mask
        let shader_gradient = SKShader(source:shader_gradient_sourcecode)
        mask.fillShader = shader_gradient
                
        //init cropNode
        let cropNode = SKCropNode()
        cropNode.maskNode = mask
        cropNode.addChild(image)
        addChild(cropNode)
    }
}
```